# list in Python3.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I found an "interesting" question about list.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list1.insert(3, list1)
print(list1)
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
POP = list1.pop()
print(POP)
[1, 2, 3]
list1.extend(['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(POP)
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Those are shown in the interactive mode. Of course, I know "insert" can only insert one object into the list. However when I insert `list1` into `list1`. It shows `[...]`, what does it mean? Moreover, `POP = list1.pop()`, isn't that pop can only return the final object to you? After extend the list, the final object should be 'c'. Why it returns the whole `list1` but without `[...]`?

Comment: It doesn't happen in just python3.6...

Comment: @n33rma In general dupes are okay... but when people start praising the heavens for them, you know something is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `list1.insert(3, list1)` you are inserting a *reference* to `list1` at index 3, so your list becomes:

```
[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [...
```

You can see this by doing:

```
>>> list1[3]
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
>>> list1[3][3]
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
>>> list1[3][3][3]
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
>>> list1[3][3][3][3]
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
```

You have infinitely nested `list1` within itself, this is why you see `[...]` because the list is infinitely long.

When you then call `POP = list.pop()` you are *removing the reference* and so `list1` becomes `[1, 2, 3]` again, and `POP` becomes a *reference* to `list1`.

Because `POP` is a reference to `list1` when you call `list1.extend(['a', 'b', 'c'])` you also update `POP` as *they're both pointing to the same list*.

---

If instead you did:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list1.insert(3, list1[:])
```

You're adding a *copy* of `list1` and so will get:

```
[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]]
```

And then calling:

```
POP = list1.pop()
```

Will make `POP` a reference to the *new* list.

At this point doing:

```
list1.extend(['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(POP)
```

Will output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

and:

```
print(list1)
```

will output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

---

Alternatively, refer to this crude drawing (which is not truly representative):

[image]

Comment: Is that somehow like Russell's Paradox?

Comment: @StephenFong No, not even remotely

Comment: but Russell's Paradox talks about a set which contain itself and therefore go infinity

Comment: @Stephen sure, but these aren't sets and this isn't set theory

Answer (score 1):

Wrt your first question. You are right that `insert` can add a single element to the list. However, that element can be anything - another number, a string, a complex object, a list, or even the list itself. Seems like Python is smart enough to figure out that printing `list1` would result in an infinite output, since `list1` has a cyclic structure like that. So it prints a placeholder which looks liks `[...]`.

---

Wrt your second question. Since `pop` returns the last element in the list, but that element is a reference to the list itself you get that reference. It also removes the reference, so it seems to you that you're getting a copy of the original list. Which is true, but the object itself has suffered the addition and removal of its last element, as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Python is reference based for when we assign an object to other its reference is copied. For copying, you need `deepcopy` or slicing in case of a list.  Below is the explanation in comments.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
#Creating list 1
list1.insert(3, list1)
#Inserting list1 refrence at index 3, means inserting its refernce. It would become [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [... so on]]]]

print(list1)
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
#in order to avoid this write like list1.insert(3, list1[:])

POP = list1.pop()
#Here pop is removing last index from list and returing modified list too

print(POP)
[1, 2, 3]
list1.extend(['a', 'b', 'c'])
# Here you are extending some other list not its refrence as previous
print(POP)
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```